# How to add two piecharts inside same div via 2.0RC1

Tags: rally

I wanted to add multiple charts in the same div

Eg:

```
<div id="chartcontainer1">
  <div id="chart1"></div>
  <div id="grid1"></div>
</div>
<div id="chartcontainer2">
  <div id="chart2"></div>
  <div id="grid2"></div>
</div>
```

How can i achieve this in rally ? i tried using renderTo but no luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
items : [{
    xtype  : 'container',
    id     : 'chartcontainer1',
    layout : 'vbox'
}],

launch : function() {
    this.down('#chartcontainer1').add([{
        xtype : 'rallychart',
        id    : 'chart1'
    },{
        xtype : 'rallygrid',
        id    : 'grid1'
    }]);
}
```

or, add the items directly in the initial config:

```
items : [{
    xtype  : 'container',
    id     : 'chartcontainer1',
    layout : 'vbox',
    items  : [{
        xtype : 'rallychart',
        id    : 'chart1'
    },{
        xtype : 'rallygrid',
        id    : 'grid1'
    }]
}]
```

You can set the config for "chartcontainer1" to be "hbox" to display horizontally, or "vbox" to display vertically. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Error is thrown "this.down(..) is null",  when i used this.down('#chartcontainer1'). How can i fix this ?

Comment: I added a couple ways you could add the items. The first one is an example of adding the chart after 'chartcontainer1' has already been created, which you would use if you had to gather some data for the charts before rendering. The second example creates the charts at the same time as the container, which you could do if you already had the data they were looking to show.